# How do I know what version of OpenGL does a source code use?

Tags: c++, opengl

I got a code, but I dont know which version of OpenGl it uses.

There were no #version pragma in the code, so I find it difficult to figure out.

How do I know which version of OpenGl is it designed for?

**Additional Info:**

It got `shader` and there were `vec2`, `vec3`, `vec4`

Comment: So is it OpenGL ES or pure OpenGL?

Comment: Well if it's not written anywhere, you can only guess based on what OpenGl features it uses...

Comment: you are right, its not written anywhere, How do I know which feature is for which?

Comment: Does it have shaders? is it using Vertex3f calls? if it does have shaders, is it using varying or locations for input variables?

Comment: It got shader and vec2, vec3, vec4, gl.getUniformLocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the OpenGL reference pages, for every function there's a list indicating in which version it appeared. The list starts at OpenGL-2.0, but that's really the lowest version you have to care about, these days.

Anyway, here's a set of heuristics to determine the OpenGL version used:

- makes use of buffer objects, i.e. calls to `glBufferData` are made → v >= 1.5
- makes use of GLSL shaders → v >= 2.0
- GLSL code uses keywords `varying` and `uniform` → v < 3
- makes use of framebuffer objects, i.e. calls to `glBindFramebuffer` are made → v >= 3.0
- makes use of vertex array objects, i.e calls to `glBindVertexArray` are made → v >= 3.3 core profile
- makes use of `glTextureStorage…` / `glTexStorage…` → v >= 4.2

Comment: omg! i have seen 'uniform mat3...' and 'varying vec...' so this might be v < 3? But could not yet pinpoint it yet. I guess you already answer my inquiry! Thanks!

Comment: @DominicGuana: Note that `varying` and `uniform` are keywords tied to the GLSL version and you can use older GLSL version profiles also with newer OpenGL versions in compatiblity profile. You'll may depreciation warnings in the compiler logs though. As I wrote, these are just a few rough heuristics.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Yes they are, but prior to 3.3 core they are not mandatory. However starting with 3.3 core you always must have a VAO in place to hold attribute–array bindings. Hence when you see VAOs being used there is a very high likelyhood that this code addresses 3.3 core or later. As I said, these are just some crude heuristics.